# django-userena "get_visible_profiles" error

Tags: django, authentication

I have been using django userena for my new project and everything worked fine. 
Now when I am browsing to /accounts/ is get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_visible_profiles'
```

I think it is related to a recent update of userena. Did anyone else encounter this issue?

Comment: http://kwanito.com/index.php/articles/80-information-technology/software/77-django-facebook-userna-accounts-manager-object-has-no-attribute-get-visible-profiles

Comment: I have already set up the model with the one to one relationship user = models.OneToOneField(User) and I am subclassing UserenaBaseProfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

I had an explicit entry:

```
objects = models.Manager()
```

In the model class. Removing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just lift the method from `UserenaBaseProfileManager` and place it in your class or derive your Manger class from that class.  I opted for the former because I build my managers as QuerySet objects and then use

```
    objects = ModelQuerySet.as_manager()
```

And Userena was built before that was possible.  I needed some methods in my Manager class so just deleting `objects =`  was not an option for me.